# Windows terminal/Ubuntu not showing all response with pretty print

Tags: ruby, pretty-print

When parsing an API response (using pretty print), most of the response is being cut off and just "..." is being shown.

```
irb(main):022:0> data = JSON.parse(response.read_body)
=>
{"data"=>
...
```

How do I display the whole response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type `data` after the assignment (at the next prompt), and you'll get the entire contents. If you don't actually need the assignment, and only want to inspect the parsed response, use `JSON.parse(response.read_body)`

By the way, the truncation behaviour of IRB is the default, but it can be changed with `IRB.CurrentContext.echo_on_assignment = true` - see https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/IRB/Context.html